# Slow booting process after adding mem=16M in boot parameters

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, armv7

My `linux-3.0` kernel was panicking saying `ERROR: Failed to allocate 0x1000 bytes below 0x0.` while booting. So I changed the bootargs and added a boot parameter `mem = 16M`. Now it boots fine but it takes a lot of time to boot. I have tried with higher `mem` value also but it does not work. Below are the logs:

```
`Machine: KZM9D
arm_add_memory: 0 0x40000000 0x1000000
Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writealloc
bootmem_init: max_low=0x266240, max_high=0x266240
<6>Section 8256 and 8250 (node 0)<c> have a circular dependency on usemap and pgdat allocations
<7>On node 0 totalpages: 0
<7>On node 1 totalpages: 0
<7>On node 2 totalpages: 0
<7>On node 3 totalpages: 0
<7>On node 4 totalpages: 0                                                                
<7>On node 5 totalpages: 0                                                                
<7>On node 6 totalpages: 0                                                                
<7>On node 7 totalpages: 0                                                                
high_memory: e0000000
Zone PFN ranges:
  Normal   0x00040000 -> 0x00041000
Movable zone start PFN for each node
early_node_map[1] active PFN ranges
    0: 0x00040000 -> 0x00041000
<7>On node 0 totalpages: 4096
<7>  Normal zone: 36 pages used for memmap
<7>  Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
<7>  Normal zone: 4060 pages, LIFO batch:0
<6>boottime: reserved memory at 0x40002000 size 0x2000
mm_init_owner
<6>PERCPU: Embedded 8 pages/cpu @c087f000 s9824 r8192 d14752 u32768
<7>pcpu-alloc: s9824 r8192 d14752 u32768 alloc=8*4096
<7>pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 
build_all_zonelists
Built 1 zonelists in Node order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 4060
Policy zone: Normal
page_alloc_init
<5>Kernel command line: console=ttyS1,115200n8 root=/dev/nfs ip=9.8.7.6 nfsroot=1.2.3.7:/tftpboot/arm/ rootwait rw mem=16M
parse_early_param
<6>PID hash table entries: 64 (order: -4, 256 bytes)
<6>Dentry cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 24576 bytes)
<6>Inode-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
<6>Memory: 16MB = 16MB total
<5>Memory: 7824k/7824k available, 8560k reserved, 0K highmem
<5>Virtual kernel memory layout:
    vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
    fixmap  : 0xfff00000 - 0xfffe0000   ( 896 kB)
    DMA     : 0xffc00000 - 0xffe00000   (   2 MB)
    vmalloc : 0xe0800000 - 0xf0000000   ( 248 MB)
    lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xe0000000   ( 512 MB)
    modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xc0000000   (  16 MB)
      .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc0704024   (7153 kB)
      .init : 0xc0705000 - 0xc0740660   ( 238 kB)
      .data : 0xc0742000 - 0xc078dc18   ( 304 kB)
       .bss : 0xc078dc18 - 0xc07f2950   ( 404 kB)
<6>Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
<6>NR_IRQS:374`
```

Comment: one reason can be a lot of page swapping going on... How much total memory does your system has ?

Comment: Try to add [initcall_debug](http://elinux.org/Initcall_Debug) option and see where is bottleneck.

Comment: @theadnangondal memory is 512MB

Comment: He needs to add timestamps to the debug info as well.  I think it is under kernel hacking and only has accuracy of the system timer.